# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint Cannot insert duplicate key error?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I have six fields **TinNo, CstNo, PanNo, CinNo, ServiceTaxNo, ExciseRegNo** in my view .Each field have default Guid eg TinNo means(TinNo= FD713788-B5AE-49FF-8B2C-F311B9CB0CC4). I need to save those six fields in same column but not in same row and same cell of **TaxInfoTaxField Table** . TaxInfoTaxFiled table contain TAXINFOTAXFIELDID, TAXFIELDID,FIELDVALUE,that is i need to save those six field values (which is entered in view) in **FieldValue** column and their id's in **TaxFieldID** column .it need to save row by row . so i decided to put that default guid's in one list and fields in another list and call where we want.And in TaxInfoTaxFieldID is new new guid for each row .

[TaxField Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSntJ.png)

[Saving Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHPu8.png)

so i decided to  put that default GUID's in one list and that 6 fields in another list

```
 ArrayList objValue = new ArrayList();
{
    objValue.Add(TITFVM.TinNo);
    objValue.Add(TITFVM.CstNo);
    objValue.Add(TITFVM.PanNo);
    objValue.Add(TITFVM.CinNo);
    objValue.Add(TITFVM.ExciseRegNo);
    objValue.Add(TITFVM.ServiceTaxNo);
   }
         List<Guid> LG = new List<Guid>();
         LG.Add(new Guid("FD713788-B5AE-49FF-8B2C-F311B9CB0CC4"));
         LG.Add(new Guid("64B512E7-46AE-4989-A049-A446118099C4"));
         LG.Add(new Guid("376D45C8-659D-4ACE-B249-CFBF4F231915"));
         LG.Add(new Guid("59A2449A-C5C6-45B5-AA00-F535D83AD48B"));
         LG.Add(new Guid("03ADA903-D09A-4F53-8B67-7347A08EDAB1"));
         LG.Add(new Guid("2F405521-06A0-427C-B9A3-56B8931CFC57"));


      var taxinfotaxfieldID = Guid.NewGuid();
      var listFiled = new List<TaxInfoTaxFiled>();

     for (var item = 0; item < objValue.Count; item++)
        {
      TaxInfoTaxFiled taxInfoObj = new TaxInfoTaxFiled()
      {
  TaxInfoTaxFieldID = taxinfotaxfieldID,
    TaxFieldID = new Guid(LG[item].ToString()),
     FieldValue = objValue[item].ToString()
     };

     listFiled.Add(taxInfoObj);
      db.TaxInfoTaxFileds .Add(taxInfoObj);
       db.SaveChanges();
     }

  return View();
    }
```

All are working fine but for second loop i got one error 
**Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_TaxInfoTaxFiled'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.TaxInfoTaxFiled'.
The statement has been terminated.**

In TaxInfoTaxFieldID it calculating same id for all iteration so only i got this error i think so . For that what shall I do? please help me to rectify this issue?

Advance Thanks..

Comment: are you storing only one time or multiple times???

Comment: i am storing  multiple field in same column for one time for one customer

Comment: is the value of `TinNo` different for all customers?

Comment: because it is a primary key it needs to be different but you are using a default key. which can be a cause of this error. you might want to try some composite key or some different primary key

Comment: wait sachin i will show you

Comment: dude  i have  6 fields in view  ok TinNo cstno panno excise reg no, servicetaxno . [enter image description here][2]     [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WcqpN.png whichis under taxField each field have default    GUID's which is saved in TaxField Table . if i enter the tinno in view means the value has been asaved in FieldValue of TaxInfoTaxfield Table and ID's is TaxFieldID of TaxInfoTaxField Table. so i tried the above method

Comment: i guess this `TaxFieldID = new Guid(LG[item].ToString())` assigns value of that unique id, but LG[item] is not unique, it is a constant list.

Comment: no error in TaxInfoTaxFieldID it is same for all iteration

Comment: When you publish a code, please make sure to format it properly. Otherwise it becomes impossible to help you. It's difficult to read your code. I think you need to move `var taxinfotaxfieldID = Guid.NewGuid();` line into the loop. That should fix your problem.

Comment: yes you are correct Kosala i tried same as like you said its worked

Comment: i gave Guid.newGuid() to taxinfotaxfieldID

Answer (score 0):

Your taxinfotaxfieldID will always be the same guid thats why you get that error also you should no insert Primary keys into the database table you could create the sql table like this

```
 
Create table TaxField
(
 TaxInfoTaxFiled INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
 TaxFieldID varchar(50),
FieldValue varchar(50)
)

or if you really want to use a Guid
Create table TaxField
(
 ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
 TaxInfoTaxFiled UNIQUE DEFAULT GUID(),
 TaxFieldID varchar(50),
FieldValue varchar(50)
)
```

This way you can avoid inserting primary key duplicates.